# iOS: Decrease delay in UIAlertView show when app enters foreground

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, uialertview, uialertsheet

I have created a password protected app. The app is allowed to run in background.
When it returns to foreground, I display an alert to prompt the user for password, by overriding the applicationWillEnterForeground: method in appdelegate like so-

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if (/*password is enabled*/)    {
        alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LOGIN"
                                               message:@"Enter app password"
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alertview.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
        pwdTF = [alertview textFieldAtIndex:0];
        [pwdTF setDelegate:self];
        [alertview show];
    }

}
```

However, the alert takes a little time to appear. During this time, the view remains vulnerable.

Is there a way to make uialertview show instantly?

Comment: You can just try to present alert on main thread for this.

Comment: Ashutosh, I'm quite a newbie to ios programming. 
Could you please provide me a link or example as to how an alert can be presented on the main thread when the app returns to foreground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    <# Write UI related code to be executed on main queue #>
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! If I understand it correctly, this block would go into the 'applicationWillEnterForeground:' appdelegate method in my case, right?